# How should I pass a String argument to clojure.core/apply

Tags: clojure

I have the following piece of code:

```
  (condp apply "string argument"
    predicate1? "Result1"
    predicate2? "Result2"
    predicate3? "Result3"
                "Else")
```

Currently, `"string argument"`, when passed to apply gets interpreted as a seq, therefore each character becomes a parameter to the predicate:

```
(apply predicate1? \s \t \r \i \n ...)
```

A simple solution would be to wrap the argument in a vector:

```
(condp apply ["string argument"] ...)
```

I'm not sure this is very idiomatic. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a more idiomatic way than using `cond` directly, binding "string argument" to a symbol and passing it to each predicate. Everything else looks confusing to people reading your code and involves extra function calls.

Extra magic could be achieved with the following helper macro:

```
(defmacro pcond
  "Translates clauses [pred result-expr] to a cond form:

   (cond
    (pred expr) result-expr
    ...)

   A single result-expr can follow the clauses, and it will be appended
   to the cond form under a generated test expression that returns logical 
   true."
  [expr & clauses]
  (let [expr-sym (gensym "expr")
        else-kw (keyword (gensym "else"))
        step (fn [[pred-form clause-form]]
               (if (= else-kw clause-form)
                 [else-kw pred-form]
                 [(list pred-form expr-sym) clause-form]))
        body (->> clauses
                  (partition 2 2 [else-kw])
                  (mapcat step))]
    `(let [~expr-sym ~expr]
       (cond ~@body))))
```

You can use it so

```
(pcond "String argument"
    predicate1 "Result1"
    predicate2 "Result2"
    "Else")
```

It macroexpands directly to cond:

```
(clojure.core/let [expr13755 "String argument"] 
   (clojure.core/cond 
     (predicate1 expr13755) "Result1" 
     (predicate2 expr13755) "Result2" 
     :else13756 "Else"))
```

Comment: Do you really think it looks confusing? I think defining the arguments before and passing the the predicates to act on that as test expressions looks so clean.

Comment: `condp` is clearly not designed for using a higher-order function as its predicate. It may look clean to you because you wrote it, but if you are used to reading other code it will take a little extra time  to understand its intent (which can be annoying). I rarely see it used like that (please prove me otherwise). Also notice that your solution involves an extra function call per predicate.

Comment: That being said, I don't advocate writing new macros. I wouldn't use `pcond` myself and usually write the code it generates directly. The OP was asking for what is idiomatic which I think is answered best with pure `cond` and the OP was likely hoping for some magic. In terms of magic I think `pcond` is sane :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that /you/ are OP, I thought you were the other guy who answered. But except for that everything I commented on applies to your post as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the anonymous function `#(%1 %2)` for what you are trying to do. IMO it's better than wrapping the `condp` expression in a vector, but either way works, neither is really straigthforward.

```
(condp #(%1 %2) "string argument"
    string? "string"
    map?    "map"
    vector? "vector"
    "something else")

;= Result1
```

**EDIT** (copied from the comments)

I'm no expert on macros, but what I've heard over and over is that you shouldn't write a macro if a function will do and `condp` provides all the elements to use the power of Clojure functions. An approach that doesn't involve macros and improves readability could be defining a function `(def apply-pred #(%1 %2))` and use it with `condp`.

Comment: You mean `#(partial %1 %2)`? `partial` by itself is not gonna work.

Comment: Yes, that's where ended up doing. But I still wonder if there's a way to use `apply`.

Comment: By the way, I think you meant `#(%1 %2)` :)

Comment: Hahaha, yeah, that's what I meant :)

Comment: You're right it will just return the function `(partial pred expr)` [edit on a previous comment, this was `(partial expr pred)`]. Just edited the answer to use an anonymous function.

Comment: Maybe it is worth creating a macro to hide away that anonymous function; can't think of a good name though.

Comment: I'm no expert on macros, but what I've heard over and over is that you shouldn't write a macro if a function will do and `condp` provides all the elements to use the power of Clojure functions. An approach that doesn't involve macros and improves readability could be defining a function `(def apply-pred #(%1 %2))` and use it with `condp`.

Comment: Hum, really makes sense.